# Golang bit only use unsigned?

Tags: go

This is a java function, i converted to golang code, but appear error.
How can I solve this problem?   please teach.

java code:

```
int p = -1;
int x = 0;
x |= 0x1 << p;
p++;
```

golang code:

```
var p int = -1
var x int = 0
x |= 0x1 << p
p++
```

> shift code type int, must be unsigned integer

Comment: I really wonder what shifting left by -1 bits should stand for. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error because as per [Go specifications](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators), bit shifting only works on unsigned ints:

```
left shift             integer << unsigned integer
right shift            integer >> unsigned integer
```